# Copy Labels to Clipboard

Tags: c#, listview, datagrid, label

I am in need of assistance, I've been looking all day in Google and so far I have not found an article for what I'm trying to do.  I am working on a little project in C# using SharpDevelop as my IDE, in the user interface for my project I have several Labels, 11 of which indicate what the field is about (i.e. "Name:" , "E-mail:") and the other 11 which will auto fill with information from a DB after pressing the Search button and typing in a keyword.

What I need to do is copy all of the labels onto the Clipboard so that the copied information may be used in another program - I have this very same application in Excel and it does what I want but I need a little more versatility thus I decided to give it a go on C#.

Is there any way to accomplish this in C#?  I have come accross ListView and DataGrids and I've thought about copying the labels to ListView (as an alternative and if possible) so that I may copy the information from ListView but with format for example:
Name:   Tim Turner

Comment: Have you looked at `Clipboard.SetText()`?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all of the output controls in a panel (or identify them however you think is best) and then you can use the following code:

```
StringBuilder clipboard = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Label label in outputPanel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    clipboard.Append(label.Text + "\n");

Clipboard.SetText(clipboard.ToString());
```

### Update

It was my understanding that you only wanted to copy the values of a series of check boxes and that would suffice. All you need to do if you would rather not iterate over a collection of controls but append values to the clipboard manually all you need to do is well, exactly that.

```
private void SetClipboard()
{
    StringBuilder clipboard = new StringBuilder();
    clipboard.Append(label1.Text + "\n");
    clipboard.Append(label2.Text + "\n");
    clipboard.Append(textBox1.Text);
    Clipboard.SetText(clipboard.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks ByteBlast, I've studied this piece of code and I think I can make the object read every label individually, why do that?  Because I also have a couple of textboxes, a combo box and 2 rich textboxes that need to be read,

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Windows Forms you can use ContextMenuStrip , by naming an option "copy", then applying named ContextMenuStrip to each label option that says ContextMenuStrip

```
    private void copyUserInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UserInfo = $"{lblFirstName.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblLastName.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblEmailAddress.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblPhysicalAddress.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblCountry.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblCompany.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblStatus.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblFirstContact.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblLastContact.Text}\n" +
                        $"{lblNotes.Text}\n ";
        Clipboard.SetText(UserInfo);
    }
```

IF you want to select FOR a single label use a second option on the ContextMenuStrip and use the following:

```
Clipboard.SetText(labelContextMenuStrip.SourceControl.Text);
```

See the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103
[C# How to copy text from different labels using only one context menu when right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621738/c-sharp-how-to-copy-text-from-different-labels-using-only-one-context-menu-when)

That was with help from @CoolBots and @Jimi.