# Get the SourceControl of a DropDownMenu

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have two click events of menu items in a ContextMenuStrip.
I can get the SourceControl of the clicked context menu item by doing this code:

```
Control c = ((sender as ToolStripItem).Owner as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl;
```

[image: Screenshot of the context menu item]

But when I use this code on a context menu item that is in another level it, returns null.

[image: Screenshot of the context menu item in another level]

How can I get the SourceControl in the click event of the second screenshot's menu item?

Comment: It' probably simpler to have a Field (something like `Control CurrentContextMenuOwner`) that is set when a `ContextMenu` is opened. Subscribe the `Opened()` event and set `CurrentContextMenuOwner = (sender as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl;`. In any of the `ToolStripMenuItems` you can then use the `CurrentContextMenuOwner` reference  to access a Control's properties. Set `CurrentContextMenuOwner` to null in the `Closing()` or `Closed()` events of the `ContextMenu`.

Comment: This is a bug in the `ContextMenuStrip` that has been there since the beginning, as far as I'm aware. You basically do have to do what @Jimi suggested.  You could probably inherit `ContextMenuStrip` and do it internally if you wanted to but, if it's a one-off, a field is the easiest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip) [SourceControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol) (the reference of the current Control where the Context Menu is activated) can be retrieved, from a [ToolStripMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem), inspecting the [OwnerItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owneritem) reference and moving upstream until the `OwnerItem` reference is `null`, then inspecting the [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner) value, which references the `ContextMenuStrip`.
(Unfortunately, the `SourceControl` reference is only available in the `ContextMenuStrip` control).

A simple alternative method is using a `Field` that references the `Control` where the current `ContextMenuStrip` has been activated (you can have just one active `ContextMenuStrip`).
This Field reference, set when the `ContextMenuStrip` is opened - by subscribing to the [`Opened()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opened) event - can then be accessed by any of the `ToolStripMenuItem`.
The Field reference is then set back to `null` when then `ContextMenuStrip` is closed.

▶ Dispose of the **`contextMenuOwner`** object when the Form closes.

**An example**:
(**`toolStripMenuItem`** is a generic name, it must be set to an actual control name).

```
Control contextMenuOwner = null;

private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOwner?.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    //(...)
}

private void contextMenuStrip1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOwner = (sender as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl;
}

private void contextMenuStrip1_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOwner = null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking here but how can I get the opposite color of a color? When I have white, black is the opposite and so on...

Comment: `Color OppositeColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.White.ToArgb() ^ 0xffffff);` Simplified. The opposite color depends on color *domain*. It could be much more complex to calculate, depending on the destination.