# How to get the contextmenustrip of deeply childed toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, winforms

Tried `GetCurrentParent()` and failed  and read all other answers.

I am working on a project where user  may click on button and generate new controls, so I have to generate them on run time.

When I created a `contextmenustrip` and added the following items

```
----------------------
  Show
----------------------
  Style -> change Color
----------------------
```

[image]

Both items should access `richtextbox`. The show click works properly but **"change color"** does not.

The problem occurs when I try to get the `richtextbox` in where the menu popped `from.Show` successfully access the `richtextbox` but `changecolor` does not.

**Here is my code**

```
 public static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox Create_rich_text_box()
  {
      System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox r = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
      r.ContextMenuStrip = Create_new_context_menu_strip();
      return r;
  }

  private static System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip Create_new_context_menu_strip()
  {
      //contextmenu
      System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip ctx = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();

      //display contents
      var show = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem("show");
      show.Click += _show_click;

      //change color
      var style = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem("Style");
      var changecolor = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem("change color"); 
      changecolor.Click += _chnge_color_click;
      style.DropDownItems.Add(changecolor);

      ctx.Items.Add(show);
      ctx.Items.Add(style);
      ctx.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            });
      return ctx;
  }
  private static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox get_current_rtx(object sender)
  {
      try
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsm = sender as System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
          var par = tsm.GetCurrentParent();
          var ctx = (par as System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip);
          return ctx.SourceControl as System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox;
      }
      catch { }
      return null;

  }
  private static void _chnge_color_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox r = get_current_rtx(sender);
      r.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");

  }
  private static void _show_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox r = get_current_rtx(sender);
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(r.Text);
      }
      catch
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This will fail");
      }
  }
```

Comment: If the `ContextMenuStrip` is the same for all `RichTextBox` controls, you don't need to create it every time which you create a new `RichTextBox`.

Comment: "Tried and failed" is not an appropriate problem description.  It probably has something to do with the SourceControl property, it has very award behavior.  It is only valid in the Opening event.  Be sure to use an event handler to store the value in a variable.

Comment: [Get Source Control Of DropDownMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103). As already mentioned, use a single ContextMenuStrip.