# How can I find which item I right clicked on without creating a ContextMenuStrip per item

Tags: c#, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I am attempting to build a TCP based controller for the servers and VMs in my house, I want each server to have a dedicated port so I can easily know which is which as there are quite a few HyperV instances running. I have designed the basic control server to my liking, but I am having trouble with ContextMenuStrips.

I have 18 servers or VMs I want to be able to manage through my program (Main purpose is running PowerShell scripts or other mundane tasks on all machines at once) but I cannot figure this part out. Each of the port listings exist within a panel, the panel contains a PictureBox and a Label. The ContextMenu Strip shown there is enabled on each of the panels which wrap the other items. How would I be able to  find which one of the panels I right clicked on to update? Would I need to create a ContextMenu per panel, is just looking at pointer position at the right click action and having some lists that define boundaries the best way or am I just unaware of a better way to do this?

[image: What I have]

Comment: [Get SourceControl Of DropDownMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103). Set the Panel's child label text.

Comment: I ran into a snag while attempting to implement the test code you provided on that post.

https://i.imgur.com/1h80Qzr.png

I did create the Opened event handler for the menu strip

https://i.imgur.com/tzFazBQ.png

I half understand what is happening with the code you provided, gonna read the documentation and hopefully find some more understanding

Comment: Did you just create it or did you also subscribed to it? If you set a breakpoint there, does it get hit?

Comment: The break point does get hit but I am not familiar with what you mean by subscribe to it

Comment: If setting a breakpoint stops the code execution inside the handler (the `contextMenuStrip1_Opened` handler), then the event is subscribed. What is `(sender as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl` at that point (the `SourceControl` value)?

Comment: It holds "{System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}" when it hit the breakpoint

Comment: Check twice what you have implemented of the code i linked. Since  `SourceControl` is a Panel control, as you have also confirmed, it cannot be null at that point, unless it's been set to null elsewhere. See that you don't have more then one ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: On a whim I commented out the setting to null on close and now it is working... I'm a bit confused but thank you very much :D I will find a way to fully implement this to my needs. You have yourself a wonderful day Jimi