# Identify List View from contextMenuStrip click

Tags: c#, listview, contextmenustrip

I have 8 listViews controls in my C# program.  I have just one contextMenuStrip that they all reference.

How can I know which listView control triggered the contextMenuStrip selection?

Comment: Check the `SourceControl` property of the `ContextMenuStrip`

Comment: See the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, it led me to the solution.

I needed to declare lvX in the class and then assign it in each of the listviews when hovered over.

```
private void lvStatus_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lvX = (ListView)sender; 
}
```

Then when the contextMenuItem was selected I simply worked with the lvX

```
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in lvX.Items)
{
  listItem.Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to your solution and **Jimi's**. Here's another one.

Just handle the `Click` event of the clicked item as follow:

```cs
private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
(((sender as ToolStripItem).Owner as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl as ListView)
    .Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList().ForEach(lvi => lvi.Checked = true); 
}
```

Or use `lvi.Checked = !lvi.Checked` if you want to toggle the `Checked` property.