# Catch the "sender" from Panel in ToolStripMenuItem_Click

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to catch the "System Object" sender of a "Panel" object, but within ToolStripMenuItem, the problem is that when it enters the ToolStripMenuItem, it takes the Sender of the ToolStrip and not that of the Panel. Could you support me or show me how to get the sender of the Panel object from the ToolStripMenuItem?

This is the code.

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim clickedPanel As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
End Sub
```

Thank you.

**Solution code.**

This is the solution to me, to move for example a Panel object.

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

        Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)

        clickedPanel.Location = New Point((clickedPanel.Location.X + 120), clickedPanel.Location.Y)

    End Sub
```

Comment: What you're asking makes no sense. The `sender` parameter in an event handler is ALWAYS the object that raised the event. If that method is handling the `Click` event of `ToolStripMenuItem` then the `sender` will ALWAYS be `ToolStripMenuItem`. Basically, what you say that you want to do is impossible so you can forget about it. You need to figure out what else you can do instead to end up with the same `Panel`. That requires considering the relationship between the menu item and the `Panel`. If you're right-clicking the `Panel` look at the `SourceControl` property of the menu.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for your answer. In this case, what I have done is that I have created Panels dynamically, and in each created panel I add a Handler event, to be able to do something with the click event, in this case what frustrates me is that in the right click, add a toolstripmenu event to get the name of the selected panel and work it. The problem is that I cannot get that event from the panel to be able to execute the toolstripmenu option.

Comment: [Get the SourceControl of a DropDownMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103) (C#, but there nothing different in VB.Net, except `DirectCast(sender, ContextMenuStrip)` instead of `sender as ContextMenuStrip`).

Comment: If you only have one level of menu items then the question already shows you want to do, i.e. cast the `sender` as type `ToolStripItem`, get the `Owner` and cast that as type `ContextMenuStrip` and then get the `SourceControl` of that: `DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl`. You can then cast that as type `Panel` if required or just use it as type `Control` if you only need members of that type.

Comment: The answer to that question addresses a bug, where the `SourceControl` property is empty when clicking items at the second level or lower in the menu. In that case, you would do as the answer shows, i.e. get the `SourceControl` in the `Opened` event handler of the menu itself, then use that reference in other event handlers as required.

Comment: For the record, you need to improve the standard of your questions going forward. In this case, you should have specifically stated that you are right-clicking on a number of `Panels` to display a `ContextMenuStrip` and, when you click an item in that menu, you want to be able to access the `Panel` that was originally clicked. A FULL and CLEAR explanation always includes what you're actually trying to achieve, not just how you're trying to achieve it. We shouldn't have to work out what you want from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one level of menu items then you can always access the `SourceControl` of the menu item that was clicked:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender,
                                                        ToolStripMenuItem).Owner,
                                             ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl,
                                  Panel)

    'Use clickedPanel here.
End Sub
```

If you have multiple levels of menu items then a bug means that the `SourceControl` will not always be populated, so you need to preget it to be sure:

```
Private clickedPanel As Panel

Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_Opened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip.Opened
    clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender,
                                         ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl,
                              Panel)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Use clickedPanel here.
End Sub
```

Comment: this is what i needed, thank you so much for your help. Just please, could you explain me about `.SourceControl`? what is the function of this?

Comment: LOOK IT UP! All you have to do is hover the mouse over it and Intellisense will provide a brief description. If you want more information, click it and press F1 to be taken straight to the documentation. Even if you don't know you can do that, nothing is stopping you using a search engine. Stop waiting for others to provide information that you can find for yourself with little effort.

Comment: no problem, although I must comment that I seek information, only that I am not 100% clear, but without problem, I appreciate your time and effort.