# ConextMenuStrip Returns Null On Shortcut Key Only

Tags: vb.net, forms, contextmenustrip

I have an odd one.  I have a Windows form with a DataGridView with a ContextMenuStrip (right click menu).  On that menu, I added a ToolStripMenuItem with a shortcut key.  When the shortcut key is activated, the handler fires as expected, but the source control of the ContextMenuStrip returns Nothing.  This works just fine when the user uses the mouse to pick the ToolStripMenuItem.  And even odder: after the user uses the mouse to pick it, the shortcut key then works just fine!

Here is the code I'm using to get the SourceControl:

```
Private Sub TestToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestToolStripMenuItem.Click
    dim currDGV As DataGridView = CType(CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl
End Sub
```

Any ideas why this is returning Nothing when the user hits the shortcut key?

Comment: If the `ToolStripMenuItem` is directly owned by the ContextMenuStrip (it's not a sub-menu), then you should have `dim currDGV = CType(CType(TestToolStripMenuItem.Owner), ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, DataGridView)`. Not if it's a sub-menu.

Comment: Isn't that what I have?  I'm failing to see the difference.

Comment: No, it's slightly different. But what matters is if this ToolStripMenuItem is a sub-menu or not. See here, anyway: [Get the SourceControl of a DropDownMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103)

Comment: ToolStripMenuItem is not a sub-menu.  Your code doesn't work in same way mine doesn't.  SourceControl returns nothing when the Shortcut Key is used to launch the menu.  It works fine when using the mouse, just like my code.

Comment: Ah, you mean you're not even opening the ContextMenuStrip, then, just pressing the ShortCutKey combination. You control should be `Me.ActiveControl` then. But in this case you have to check the Type of the control, to see whether it's a DataGridView, since it may be any of the Controls that have the same ContextMenuStrip set as the Property value.

Comment: ```Me.ActiveControl``` returns the ```SplitContainer``` that houses the DataGridView.  Since that same SplitContainer contains a separate DataGridview, I can't differentiate which ContextMenuStrip actually was selected.  Unfortunately, I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: What do you think using the mouse to select the menu does differently that the shortcut key doesn't?  Perhaps I could fake that action if we can figure out what it is?  This seems like a vb.net bug.

Comment: The ContextMenuStrip it's a .Net Control, the same *features* apply to C#. Anyway, it's not the ContextNmenuStrip, the *problem* is the SplitContainer.

Comment: (Sorry, I had to move away from screen). So, the SplitContainer *steals* the `ActiveControl` role, but you can get it back with something like:  `var active = this.ActiveControl; if (active is SplitContainer split) { var sourceControl = split.ActiveControl; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208947/discussion-between-dan-and-jimi).